# Is INSERT-WHERE atomic?

Tags: sql, atomic

Is the following SQL atomic? is there any risk for two rows with the same `id`?

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table] (id, whatever)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' as id,
             'something'                            as whatever)
         AS input
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [dbo].[table]
                  WHERE id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001')
```

I'm using it in Azure Synapse, in which there is no primary key enforcement and `MERGE`-`UPDATE` is not allowed from whatever reason.